# Nothing showing up when using includegraphics

Tags: graphics, floats

I'm trying to put an image (screenshot) in my article, but nothing is happening. No message error, no box, just nothing. I'm using Texmaker, and compiling using quick build. If I compile with PDFLaTex, it doesn't make a difference.

I tried putting an fbox around it, and still nothing.

Thank you.

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{circuitequi.png}
    \caption{Circuit équivalent au cable coaxial}
\end{figure} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Where is `\documentclass[..]{...}` ... `\begin{document}` ... `\end{document}`?

Comment: I suppose your problem is caused by the image file not being in the correct folder location.

Having tried your code (I agree with Werner, please complete it to a MWE [1]) everything seems to work fine.

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_Working_Example

Comment: Added the correct lines of codes. Also, both files are in the same folder.

Comment: Please, add the complete log file after compiling the very same code you wrote in the question.

Comment: egreg, I ran the exact code and it worked. However, in my article (longer code), it still doesn't work. Both codes are in the same file. It's very strange. How can I add the log file for that code?

Comment: Do you still get the caption (i.e. is it the figure environment that's missing, or just the image itself)? If you do see the caption, try zooming in on the area above it. Is there definitely nothing there?

Comment: No caption. There's is just nothing.

Comment: I replaced the h by H, and it worked! Thanks for the help everybody.

Comment: are you sure the figure was not printed (which would be very odd) or just not printed where you expected (`[h]` makes it quite likely that the figure is printed at the end of the document)